# Splitting a polygon into parts

Tags: java, opengl, split, polygon

In my application I work with OpenGL and large arrays of data.

One of the things I need to do is I receive multiple "simple" polygons that can be either convex or concave. By simply I mean geometrical definition - polygons without holes and intersecting edges.

I receive this poligons in the form of linked loop of points (vertices), where each Vi is connected to Vi-1 and Vi+1 points and nothing else. The last point is also connected to the first, giving us a loop as a result.

I will say right now that I figured out polygon triangulation, and it works like a charm (I used ear-clipping method for now).

But, I need to build LOTS of those polygons, millions of them. To minimize the load I decided to split my world into "chunks", squares like in Minecraft. I then use frustum culling and other optimizations methods to either render or discard/simplify these chunks and meshes in them.

So, what I want to do is: if the polygon I received lies in several different chunks - then I want to split it into meshes for each of those chunks. Basically, I want to create multiple polygons that are divided on chunk borders, and THEN triangulate them and create meshes for rendering.

As a result I want to have one (or several) contours that I can then triangulate.

here's a picture of my task:

[image]

I made an algorythm for splitting it myself that I thought would work, but I found that it only works if the contour in any given chunk doesn't break up, like you see in the example (in other words if there's only one figure in any given chunk).

I thought to ask here if anyone knows any good algorythms for that task? I'll probably come up with something myself, but practice shows that there's almost always a better and simpler ready-made solution out there. I'd really appreciated it if someone could give me a useful link or an article, if not with a solution itself, then something that could give ideas.

Comment: @genpfault, the proposed duplicate does *not* answer this question. The selected answer there doesn't even give an example of *how* those steps are achieved. This question also has an additional requirement that the resulting polygons are *separate* after clipping. That may be a trivial step to some people, but it is still more information required to answer *this* question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at work at the moment, because it's weekend, so I'll be trying/testing the things on Monday.

What I came up with at the moment, however, is a very simple solution.

1. test all points in the contour.
2. If point `i` and point `i+1` don't belong to the same chunk (which I can test easily):
3. then find an intersection between chunk border and the line made by these two points.
4. add this new point to the contour between the original two points.
5. When every edge of the polygon was tested like that - triangulate it.
6. because we have points on the edges of the chunks - then during triangulation the triangles will fit exactly into chunk borders
7. for each triangle, decide which chunk it belongs to and generate the mesh in THAT chunk.

I won't go into details of some optimization ideas - like not needing to evaluate resulting triangles if the entire figure fits within the same chunk.

Comment: Tried it, this doesn't handle chunk corners too well either.

Answer (score -1):

This is a stab in the dark at writing some pseudo code that may work. Feel free to implement it and select your own answer with the actual code if it works.

---

First, convert your vertex array to a double linked list that loops from the last element to the first element. Or it may be better to model it as an undirected graph instead, because a point may have missing neighbours.

Then apply the algorithm below for each quadrant, starting with the full polygon each time. You can cut down the size of that polygon by culling vertices that are outside of the quadrant **and** at least 1-neighbour away from edges that cross the cutting lines.

```
// We need to keep track of the points that we insert on the cutting lines
let LIX = List of X-Cut-Line Intersection Points
let LIY = List of Y-Cut-Line Intersection Points

foreach Edge AB in Poly where A is inside the quadrant, B outside
    // Insert points into the polygon that intersect the X-Cut-Line
    if AB Intersects X-Cut-Line
        let Ix = Intersection Point
        Insert Ix between AB so that A<->B becomes A<->Ix
        B can be removed from the polygon now
        Add Ix to LIX
    // Insert points into the polygon that intersect the Y-Cut-Line
    if AB.Intersects Y-Cut-Line
        let Iy = Intersection Point
        Insert Iy between AB so that A<->B becomes A<->Iy
        B can be removed from the polygon now
        Add Iy to LIY

// Then iterate pairs of points along each cutting line to join them
sort LIX by X Ascending
while (LIX.Length > 0)
    let P0 = LIX[0]
    let P1 = LIX[1]
    Link P0 and P1
    Remove P0 and P1 from LIX

sort LIY by Y Ascending
while (LIY.Length > 0)
    let P0 = LIY[0]
    let P1 = LIY[1]
    Link P0 and P1
    Remove P0 and P1 from LIY
```

Finally, you can look for cycles in the resulting linked list/graph to find the new polygons. Each cycle should in theory not contain points from the other cycles already detected so it is an individual polygon.

Comment: I had something similar going the first time I tried to handle this promblem. The thing is - this algorythm doesn't really handle corners well, and also wouldn't work (I think) for cases when we have several separate pieces  of a poly inside the chunk that aren't linked together.

Comment: @VladKozmyuk, The last step (not written in pseudocode) is to find individual loops in the resulting graph/linkedlist. That will take care of identifying the separate pieces. For corners, do you mean a point that lies on the X and Y cutting line?